# How to explain "completionHandler(true) "

Tags: ios, swift

I am following a tutorial online regarding a TableView Cell swipe action.
I can explain to myself every line, except `completionHandler(true)`

This is the code snippet

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
        //Delete
        self.restaurantNames.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.restaurantLocations.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.restaurantTypes.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.restaurantIsVisited.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.restaurantImages.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        // Call completion handler to dismiss the action button
        completionHandler(true)
    }

    let shareAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Share") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
        let defaultText = "Just checking in at" + self.restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [defaultText], applicationActivities: nil)
        self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        // Call completion handler to dismiss the action button
        completionHandler(true)
    }

    let swipeConfiguration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, shareAction])

    return swipeConfiguration
}
```

I don't quite understand what does this mean?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third parameter of the `UIContextualAction` handler is a closure that tells `UIContextualAction` whether or not you performed the action.  By calling `completionHanlder(true)` you're notifying `UIContextualAction` that you performed the requested action.  If, for example, there was an error in your handler that precluded you from performing the desired action, you can notify the handler by calling `completionHandler(false)`.

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextualaction/handler

Comment: ... which still doesn't explain what that difference DOES to the UI.

Answer (score 11):

All of the existing answers just paste Apple's documentation which answers precisely nothing.  It says when it should be called but nothing about what it does to the UI.

As far as I can tell, calling completionHandler with either value will collapse the buttons.  You can see this in action by calling the completion handler in a `dispatch_after` block with a delay.  Specifying true vs. false makes no difference in my tests.

I have a feeling that I'm missing something, but Apple's documentation is opaque here.

Answer (score 3):

**Explanation:** You call the completion handler with true to indicate you performed the action or false if you could not for some reason.

**Check below demo code work:**

```swift
func contextualToggleFlagAction(forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {

    var email = data[indexPath.row]

    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal,
                                    title: "Flag") { (contextAction: UIContextualAction, sourceView: UIView, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) in

        if email.toggleFlaggedFlag() {

            self.data[indexPath.row] = email
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)

            completionHandler(true) // your task is successfully done.
        } else {

            completionHandler(false) // With some reason you unable to perform task so now you returning false.
        }
    }

    action.image = UIImage(named: "flag")
    action.backgroundColor = email.isFlagged ? UIColor.gray : UIColor.orange
    return action
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the comment before the `completionHandler` line explains the purpose. The completion handler is a closure which must be called at the end of the action to dismiss the action and to pass a status value.

More information from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextualaction/handler)

> **completionHandler**
>
> The handler block for you to execute after you have performed the action. This block has no return value and takes the following parameter:
>
> `actionPerformed`
>
> A Boolean value indicating whether you performed the action. Specify `true` if you performed the action or `false` if you were unable to perform the action for some reason.